# the JSON Response is unreadable on the adapter class but visible on the logcat using retrofit http library

Tags: android, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I have followed guide from https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/ to get the json response. But the response is not coming on the RecyclerView after parsing on the Adapter class. But the JSON response is visible in the logcat that I created. Please check out my scripts below:

EkonomiFragment.java

```
final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewEkonomi);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext().getApplicationContext()));

    ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

    Call<EkonomiResponse> call = apiService.getEkonomi(rssUrlE);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<EkonomiResponse>(){
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<EkonomiResponse> call, Response<EkonomiResponse> response){
            List<Ekonomi> ekonomis = response.body().getItems();
            for(int x=0; x<ekonomis.size(); x++){
                Log.i("Judul", ekonomis.get(x).getTitle());
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "JSON Ekonomi: " + ekonomis);

            //Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(new EkonomiAdapter(ekonomis, R.layout.list_item_berita_e, rootView.getContext()));
            //recyclerView.setAdapter(new EkonomiAdapter(ekonomis, R.layout.list_item_berita_e, rootView.getContext()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<EkonomiResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e(TAG, t.toString());
            Toast.makeText(rootView.getContext(), "Gagal", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

EkonomiAdapter.java

```
public class EkonomiAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EkonomiAdapter.EkonomiViewHolder>{

private List<Ekonomi> ekonomis;
private int rowLayout;
private Context context;

public static class EkonomiViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView ekonomiLayout;
    TextView newsTitle;
    TextView pubDate;
    WebView newsDescription;

    public EkonomiViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        ekonomiLayout = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.berita_layout_e);
        newsTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_e);
        pubDate = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pubDate_e);
        newsDescription = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.description_e);
    }
}

public EkonomiAdapter(List<Ekonomi> ekonomis, int rowLayout, Context context) {
    this.ekonomis = ekonomis;
    this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public EkonomiViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
    return new EkonomiViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull EkonomiViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Log.i("JSON", ekonomis.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.newsTitle.setText(ekonomis.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.pubDate.setText(ekonomis.get(position).getPubDate());
    holder.newsDescription.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    holder.newsDescription.loadData(ekonomis.get(position).getDescription(), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
} }
```

Comment: Could you post some log in onBindViewHolder?

Comment: I've added log at onBindViewHolder but it doesn't appear in logcat

Comment: So I guess your adaper is not really work,is there some error log in your logcat console?

Comment: My suggestions:1. create a list and add some data into it then set list to your adapter,2.check whether is it work fine

Comment: @KalamTaufiq if `getItemCount()` returns count as 0 in adapter class, the adapter class won't execute further code. So, log inside `onBindViewHolder()` will not help you to debug the code. Check @Mujahid Khan's answer below for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why getItemCount is 0? it will make the recycler view not to read the list. So in the getItemCount method write, return ekonomis.size();